# cancel retrofit request using RxJava

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

we use this code to cancel a request in retrofit:

```
call.cancel();
```

but when using retrofit with RxJava2, How can we cancel the request? I used Disposable.dispose() like below, but not worked correctly. any solution ?

```
Disposable disposable = onCallBackRetrofitRx.askUploadFile(body, dirName, photoIndex)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ObUploadFile>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ObUploadFile ob) {
                        //sth...
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        //sth...
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        //sth...
                    }
                });
```

and this one:

```
 disposable.dispose();
```

the askUploadFile interface is:

```
  @Multipart
@POST("UploadFile")
Observable<ObUploadFile> askUploadFile (
        @Part MultipartBody.Part    image,
        @Part("dir")                RequestBody dir,
        @Part("PhotoIndex")         RequestBody PhotoIndex
);
```

and my retrofit implementation

```
@Module(includes = {NetworkModule.class})
public class ServerModule {

String apiUrl = Configs.DOMAIN;

@BaseScope
@Provides
public OnCallBackRetrofitRx provideRetrofitCallBack(Retrofit retrofit){
    return retrofit.create(OnCallBackRetrofitRx.class);
}

@Provides
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Gson gson){
    return new Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .baseUrl(apiUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
}}
```

Comment: That's the way to cancel it. How is it not working as expected? What library versions are you using?

Comment: @akarnokd I used latest versions of retrofit and rxjava2, but I don't know whats the problem !!!!

Comment: How do you know you have a problem then? Do you get a crash, an exception? Does the file upload in full even if you cancel it?

Comment: @akarnokd when I debug the app, onNext() callback method  invoked, also, the file uploads to server successfully too.

Comment: How is `askUploadFile` implemented?

Comment: @akarnokd I updated the question.....

Comment: if you check the source retrofit's call adapter calls `call.cancel()` when the observable is disposed. https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/CallEnqueueObservable.java

Comment: Dispose will dispose of the subscription, meaning that the subscriber will not be notified of the result, it doesn't meant that the work will stop.

Comment: @mahmoudrezamohammadian Hey, i have the same problem as you, i'm starting Retrofit 2 Multi-Part request and i want to cancel it at some time. I've tried via disposable.dispose() but the request is not canceling and continue uploading.
Did you find any solution about this?